# Is there a relation between the ability to recognize faces and the number of people one meets daily?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Does the average number of different people one sees daily affect one's ability to recognize faces?

Compare a person who lives in a crowded city (and thus sees many different faces daily) with a person who lives in a small community like a village and sees few people daily (all of them familiar). Based on this alone would the general ability to recognize faces be different?

Has there been any research done on this topic?